npm : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. any body have answer. Help me
Anybody can solve this error.
I faced this error while running this command (npm create vite@latest) in the PowerShell terminal in VS Code.
So, what should I do to solve this error? I am also still trying to identify this error.

Have a look at some of the duplicate questions here - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+Running+scripts+is+disabled - they’ll give you an answer and lots of background information as well.

You need to run Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted in a Powershell prompt with administrative rights. You also possibly need to restart you computer after that.
Source

This fix worked for me. Thanks!

This worked for me.  I suddenly started getting this same error when running npm install in the VS Code terminal.  The problem started after uninstalling node and then installing nvm.  After running the recommended command in Powershell with admin I was able to run npm install from VS Code terminal again.

Thanks, this worked! Restarting was not necessary in my case

God bless you!!


Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted                                                                        'Set-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                             operable program or batch file.


Thankyou so much!! Another thing to note is Powershell is not the same as command prompt..

first check you status with the command 
Get-ExecutionPolicy 
to check whether it's restricted or others, it should Restricted if you face this error 
Solution:

run Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
Type


RemoteSigned


solved. You're good to go.



Get-ExecutionPolicy                                                                                     'Get-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                             operable program or batch file.


PS C:\Users\anand> Get-ExecutionPolicy // first run this 
Restricted // if restricted run below code 
PS C:\Users\anand> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser

cmdlet Set-ExecutionPolicy at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ExecutionPolicy: RemoteSigned // remotesigned in run 

PS C:\Users\anand>

